# ffmpeg: How can a MOV with transparent background be created?

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha, mov

I'm trying - with no success at all - to convert the green pixels of a background into transparent ones and output the result as clip with ffmpeg. N.b. I do *not* want to lay the clip over anything; I'm not having a problem with that. What I want is a clip with transparent background for the OpenShot video editor (the chromakey filter of which doesn't work satisfyingly).

What I have tried (amongst 1 zillion other things over the last 15 hrs.) was

```
ffmpeg.exe -i in.mov -vf chromakey=0x008001:0.115:0.0 -c:v qtrle out.mov
```

but the pixels simply would not be transparent. Seemingly, nothing happens. I reckon the filter is ok, because it works fine in a complex chain (overlaying a background image).

The output of ffprompt -show_stream -show_format of out.mov is as follows:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=qtrle
codec_long_name=QuickTime Animation (RLE) video
profile=unknown
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/30
codec_tag_string=rle
codec_tag=0x20656c72
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=bgra
level=-99
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=progressive
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=30/1
avg_frame_rate=30/1
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=54789
duration=3.566992
bit_rate=822383192
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=107
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=DataHandler
TAG:encoder=Lavc57.64.101 qtrle
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=926
start_time=0.020998
duration_ts=157481
duration=3.570998
bit_rate=132103
max_bit_rate=132103
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=153
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=DataHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=out.mov
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=3.567000
size=366708874
bit_rate=822447712
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=qt
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=qt
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.56.101
[/FORMAT]
```

I have a "sample" clip which shows the behaviour I want, with the following stream and information:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=qtrle
codec_long_name=QuickTime Animation (RLE) video
profile=unknown
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/24
codec_tag_string=rle
codec_tag=0x20656c72
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=bgra
level=-99
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=progressive
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=24/1
avg_frame_rate=24/1
time_base=1/12288
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=74760
duration=6.083984
bit_rate=49226848
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=146
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=DataHandler
TAG:encoder=Lavc57.24.102 qtrle
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=LC
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/48000
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=48000
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/48000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=293856
duration=6.122000
bit_rate=53537
max_bit_rate=128000
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=288
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=eng
TAG:handler_name=DataHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=templateOK.mov
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=0.000000
duration=6.144000
size=37478506
bit_rate=48800138
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=qt
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=qt
TAG:encoder=Lavf57.25.100
[/FORMAT]
```

and I simply am not able to spot the relevant difference.

The input, output and the working template can be found [here](https://www.wot.at/owncloud/index.php/s/KRmtBt3a2J7zDCt).

(The security issue you might see when clicking the link comes from the server certificate being self-signed. You can accept a temporal exception. Btw: The ridiculous file size of the output file will be the next nut to crack. Probably something about compression.)

Comment: Try with `-c:v png`

Comment: Thanks, Mulvya!

I have. As I've said, I just had 15 hrs. of trial and error. Mainly error. :-(((

Comment: Have you tried overlaying the encoded video within ffmpeg? How are you checking the transparency?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. That's why I'm confident the filter setting itself ('chromakey=0x008001:0.115:0.0') is working fine.

Comment: If you have verified the *encoded* file, then the MOV is also good. It's an issue with your editor. You can try a different pixel format `-pix_fmt rgba`.

Comment: I would, but *all* formats except argb yield the ffmpeg warning

"Incompatible pixel format 'rgba' for codec 'qtrle', auto-selecting format 'argb'"

What other codecs can handle transparency? Unfortunately I'm seemingly unable to learn this from the ffmpeg-documentation. (I tried, honestly.)

Comment: Your out.mov has transparency within Vegas Pro. How are you checking the transparency?

Comment: Oh f...! I've been barking up the wrong tree all the time!

I "checked" transparency by playing the video in vlc, where I expected to see a black background - which simply would not happen: the green cloth looks much the same like in in.mov.

So it's simply vlc ignoring the alpha-channel, isn't it?

After your hint I put the clip into the editor (OpenShot) - and voilà!

Thanks a *lot*! That idea would never ever have occured to me! I highly appreciate your help, and especially thanks for bothering! (As you might have guessed by now, I'm a complete newbie to video editing.)

Cheers!

Comment: (Aside: we don't use [solved] devices here, or add answers into question posts. If you would like to add an answer over and above what is already below, we welcome self-answers too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A video player will not show transparency, as you've discovered.

Transparency does not really exist in video. Each pixel has to have *some* color. Transparency is implemented by adding another component, called alpha. The value of the alpha channel at a position determines how the application handling the file blends the colored pixel at that position with the colored pixels of the layer(s) beneath it (themselves weighted by *their* alpha). If there are no layers beneath, as is the case in a video player, no blending occurs and the stored color is shown. If alpha for a pixel is `0` then the color is nullified and the layer beneath completely shows through, and hence 'transparency'.

Long story short: check transparency in a app which can composite, like a video editor or VFX app.